# Sublime Text - Python - Tooltips or Bubbles for Docstrings and Linting messages

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I've been testing using Sublime Text as a Python IDE, and there are two things I can't figure out how to do via settings or plugins, both related to tooltips / bubbles.  I'm under the impression from comments I've seen about a (non-existent?) tooltip API that these features may not be possible at this time.

(1) The first is getting a popup of the docstring for a function, as in IPython (picture below).  I know some autocompleters will fill in the autocomplete box with a list of arguments, or put something in the status bar, but I'm looking for something that pops up in place.  (Or a documentation pane like Spyder's that automatically shows the documentation for the function you're on).

(2) The second is being able to get a tooltip of the lint error, as in Spyder.  My mouse cursor disappeared from the screenshot, but it's hovering over the exclamation mark icon the gutter.

[image: IPython Tooltip Example]

[image: Spyder Lint Tooltip]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no tool tip API in ST, so the features you want are not available. I'm sure lots of plugin developers are hoping for this feature and if/when it's released, there will be a large number of updates to existing plugins to use the functionality.

Comment: Fair enough, hope it gets added.

Comment: not the correct answer anymore. See yincrash answer for ST3

Answer (score 3):

This exists now in [build >= 3070](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/25) of SublimeText 3. Plugins have already started using it. For Python, [Anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda) is an example of a plugin with tooltips.